# Open Chrome Developer Tools in Its Own Window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Chrome Developer Tools. I'm trying to open it in its own window. Other answers indicate a small button on the bottom left. I'm afraid I lack such a button. How do I open the Chrome Developer tools in its own window?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click and hold the icon in the top right next to the close icon:

[image]

From Chrome 41, you are able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Mac OS X) to be able to toggle between these views.

Comment: The click and hold is what I needed! Thanks.